# Function declared as pure, but this expression (potentially) reads from the environment or state and thus requires "view"

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging

I can't work out how to modify this...When I change pure to view I get a different error:

```
function balanceOf(address _owner) public pure returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}
```

changing to view gives this error:

```
Overriding function changes state mutability from "pure" to "view".
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    ^
Spanning multiple lines.
```

Comment: Is balanceOf overriding a parent function of the same signature with the state mutability "pure"? An erc20 balanceOf function definitely shouldn't be pure because it needs to read balances from the state.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had a function further up that was pure, thanks!!! been looking at this for hours, its all blending together LOL

Comment: I've got another error, unction declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable. How would I change this?

    function coinAge() public view returns (uint myCoinAge) {
        myCoinAge = getCoinAge(msg.sender,now);
    }

Answer (score 2):

You're fine. Because you're reading a state variable with Blockchain data (ie the reserved keywords like tx, msg, and so on) it's giving you a compiler warning as the compiler is not smart enough to understand that you're not actually modifying anything.

Also make sure `getCoinAge` is also marked view. http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html?highlight=Pure

Comment: Thanks for the help :-)

I believe I have it working now but I have posted the entire script and have asked for people to check so that it will function as I expect. Would you mind taking a look?

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37621/i-have-written-a-script-can-someone-please-check-over-it